# access local HTML files without allowing user to modify them

Tags: c#, html

I have a client application that currently accesses static HTML files from a server via HTTPS.
Since these files never change, I would like my application to access them from the local file system. However, I do not want the user to be able to modify the HTML, so I would like to somehow embed the files in my assembly, so nobody can tinker with them. Is this possible?

Comment: do you need to do an intial download or are they available from the get go in the assembly?

Comment: You cannot prevent someone with direct access to a file to modify it. Embed the file in your executable as you will, that won't prevent people from tampering with the executable itself.

Comment: What if you created another password protected user account, similar to nVidia's UpdatusUser, gave it ownership and only allowed it to edit the file? It could run a service or something to do the actual updating. Your program may need to watch for changes to the user and the html file's permissions.

Comment: @Daniel: I would like to avoid an initial download and use assembly from get go

Comment: Would it work to just use something like ATTRIB to make the files read-only? Preventing inadvertent change -or at least giving the user a big fat warning- seems doable. And if necessary you can always get a fresh copy via https: On the other hand preventing _all malicious_ modifications to the files is somewhere between very difficult and impossible - certainly not worth the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the local file system has some sort of "date last modified" for each file, just store the files in the file system. Also calculate a hash of the contents for each file and keep a private (hidden) record of what you know the hashes should be. Then when your app fetches a file, have it also fetch the date last changed and recalculate the contents hash too. If either the date last changed or the hash is different from what you know it should be, have your app fetch a fresh copy via https: and use that instead.

(If a user [hacker?] is really determined to thwart your scheme and has physical access to the computer, they'll find a way no matter what you do. If physical access is possible, you can't be perfect [although you can prevent "most" modifications by making it so time-consuming the user decides it's not worth it].)